# Ajax BeginForm - Call action on a different controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the following scenario: 
- Area A -> PartialView A -> It is using Ajax.BeginForm calling action "Save" on Controller A
- Area B -> View B

I inserted "PartialView A" into "View B" but the Ajax.BeginForm form action is calling Controller B action instead of Controller A.

PartialView A:

```
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, new AjaxOptions<br>
        {
            Url = Url.Action("Save", "ControllerA", null, Request.Url.Scheme),
            HttpMethod = "Post",
        }
```

Controller A action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Model model)
    {
    }
```

My goal is to reuse/insert the partial view into other views without having to add any other action to the view's controller. How to solve this scenario? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Try changing `Url.Action("Save", "ControllerA", null, Request.Url.Scheme)` to `Url.Action("Save", "ControllerA", new { area = "AreaA" }, Request.Url.Scheme)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Wablab but no luck.

Comment: did you solve problem

Answer (score 6):

why not just simply use the Ajax.BeginForm params?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "ControllerA", null, new AjaxOptions(){
 HttpMethod = "POST"
}, new { id = "someRandomForm" }))
{
   <div>
      <!-- your html code -->
   </div>
}
```

add `null` after controller parameter and before the `new AjaxOptions()` parameter to somehow make us hit the controller we wanted, which is `ControllerA`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make the Ajax.BeginForm to work as I want so my workaround was to use JQuery ajax call using the specific controller/action I need to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "ControllerA", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
```

Comment: That actually was my first attempt. No luck on that.

Comment: can you add your controller into question

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.